# Static list is initialized with different items but has only one type during runtime

Tags: c#, list

I was trying to emulate an enum in C# i can use with string values by using a class with static only members like here:

```
internal class TruckSizeType
{
  private static string? Value;

  private TruckSizeType(string value) { Value = value; }

  public static TruckSizeType SMALL { get { return new TruckSizeType("small"); }}
  public static TruckSizeType MEDIUM { get { return new TruckSizeType("medium"); }}
  public static TruckSizeType BIG { get { return new TruckSizeType("big"); }}
  public static TruckSizeType GIANT { get { return new TruckSizeType("giant"); }}
  public static List<TruckSizeType> ALL = new ()
  {
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    BIG,
    GIANT
  };

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Value ?? "";
  }
}
```

For some reason, the list member "ALL" shows up as filled with 4 members (which is correct) during runtime but all of those are of the type GIANT. I cannot figure out why all the members are of type GIANT in the ALL list when i initialized them with all of the 4 different types instead. Does anybody understand this? I am not a c# programmer but have quite a bit of experience in OOP languages. Perhaps it is a case of missing the obvious. Here is a screenshot from the debugger showing the value of the list after assignment:
[image]

Comment: Exactly - the way you have setup the properties, `TruckSizeType.SMALL != TruckSizeType.SMALL` is true.

Comment: Yes, the static field for the internal was just pure stupidity. I knew it must be something obvious but it was late and i needed to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use static fields instead of properties so you don't create new instances each time you reference them, and you need to have an actual class with a private value to hold the string:

```
internal class TruckSizeType {
    private readonly string Value;
    private TruckSizeType(string value) => Value = value;

    public static readonly TruckSizeType SMALL = new TruckSizeType("small");
    public static readonly TruckSizeType MEDIUM = new TruckSizeType("medium");
    public static readonly TruckSizeType BIG = new TruckSizeType("big");
    public static readonly TruckSizeType GIANT = new TruckSizeType("giant");
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<TruckSizeType> ALL = new List<TruckSizeType>() { SMALL, MEDIUM, BIG, GIANT }.AsReadOnly();

    public override string ToString() => Value ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I missed the static part particularly on the internal value field.

Comment: Here's the tricky one: The `?? ""` part in `ToString` isn't necessary when used normally.  However, one could use reflection to create a new instance with `null` for the value, causing `ToString` to return `null`. That's more of a "you reap what you sew" kind of thing. The guard isn't hurting anything, but it's only accounting for the abuse case.

Comment: @madreflection I kind of feel the same way about the `readonly` on the `Value` field.

Comment: That's a worse abuse case, though, because the prefab instances can be changed without `readonly` on `Value`, meaning that a it can affect consumers that expect those instances to be correct. Coalescing in `ToString` only accounts for non-prefab instances initialized with `null`, and although those could still get passed around, at least they don't [reference-]compare equal to any prefab instance and can be ruled out by validation.

Comment: Like I said, it's tricky. And by that, I'm referring to the decision whether to account for that worst abuse case. It's a matter of perspective (which is what makes it tricky). Do you think about it purely from a C# perspective, or do you think about it from the broader, anything-could-try-to-do-anything-with-it perspective? I'm not advising either, at least not as far as that coalescing expression is concerned.

Comment: @madreflection i am by no means well versed in internals or special keywords with C# unfortunately. I added the ?? to the ToString to stop the warning which is quite annoyingly handled to my experience at the moment in general with nullable types. Its the same with for example when you do a null check or other validation before a piece of code and the warning is gone, but when you extract the validation code into a separate method it does not recognize anymore that it is "still safe" - the same code is still being run in the same place preventing access by thrown exceptions before.

Comment: You were getting the warning because you declared `Value` as `string?`. The code above declares it as `string` so you wouldn't get the warning.

Comment: @madreflection But changing the prefab instances `Value` field won't change the comparison of the objects to the prefab objects, so it would only matter for (possible) output of the name, so I don't think it is worse... at least until a way of selecting a prefab instance by name is added.

Comment: Frankly, I think this whole "emulated enum" thing is a bad idea. Better to use a real `enum` with custom attributes on the fields for metadata, and write extension methods for retrieving that metadata.